# Stack Overflow 64 characters limit

Tags: python, mysql

I'm creating a Database from excel files scraped from the web, the problem is that the source lacks a pattern, the name of the columns vary a lot and sometimes it exceeds the 64 characters limitation from MySQL. My solution by now is running the script and replace each word I find to a reduced version. The problem is that there is too much data and the replace library is getting huge.

Here's an example of one table being created after replaces:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ecorodovias_concessões_e_serviços__bal_at` (
    `index` TEXT, 
    `ATIVO TOTAL` FLOAT(53), 
    `ATIVO CIRCULANTE` FLOAT(53), 
    `CAIXA E EQS CAIXA` FLOAT(53), 
    `CAIXA E BANCOS` FLOAT(53), 
    `APL FINS` FLOAT(53), 
    `APL FINS AV VAL` FLOAT(53), 
    `TIT NEG` FLOAT(53), 
    `TIT DISP VENDA` FLOAT(53), 
    `APL FINS AV CUSTO AMORTIZADO` FLOAT(53), 
    `TIT MANTIDOS ATÉ O VENCIMENTO` FLOAT(53), 
    `CONTAS RECEBER` FLOAT(53), 
    `CLIENTES` FLOAT(53), 
    `OUTRAS CONTAS RECEBER` FLOAT(53), 
    `ESTOQUES` FLOAT(53), 
    `ATIVOS BIOLÓGICOS` FLOAT(53), 
    `TRIB REC` FLOAT(53), 
    `TRIB CORRENTES REC` FLOAT(53), 
    `DSP ANTECIPADAS` FLOAT(53), 
    `PRÊMIOS E SEGUROS APROPRIAR` FLOAT(53), 
    `OUTROS ATIVOS CIRCULANTES` FLOAT(53), 
    `ATIVOS NCO VENDA` FLOAT(53), 
    `ATIVOS OP DESCS` FLOAT(53), 
    `OUTROS` FLOAT(53), 
    `TIT E VAL MOB` FLOAT(53), 
    `DIV E JUROS CAPITAL` FLOAT(53), 
    `OUTROS CRED` FLOAT(53), 
    `EMPRESAS LIGADAS` FLOAT(53), 
    `ATIVO NCI` FLOAT(53), 
    `ATIVO REALIZÁVEL LONGO PRAZO` FLOAT(53), 
    `TRIB DIFERIDOS` FLOAT(53), 
    `IR E CS DIFERIDOS` FLOAT(53), 
    `CRED PT RELS` FLOAT(53), 
    `CRED COLIGADAS` FLOAT(53), 
    `CRED CONTROLADORES` FLOAT(53), 
    `CRED OUTRAS PT RELS` FLOAT(53), 
    `OUTROS ATIVOS NCIS` FLOAT(53), 
    `DPST JDC` FLOAT(53), 
    `INV` FLOAT(53), 
    `PART SOCIETÁRIAS` FLOAT(53), 
    `PART COLIGADAS` FLOAT(53), 
    `OUTRAS PART SOCIETÁRIAS` FLOAT(53), 
    `PROPRIEDADES INV` FLOAT(53), 
    `IMOB` FLOAT(53), 
    `IMOB OP` FLOAT(53), 
    `IMOB ARRADO` FLOAT(53), 
    `IMOB ANDAMENTO` FLOAT(53), 
    `INTA` FLOAT(53), 
    `CONT CSS` FLOAT(53), 
    `OBRAS ANDAMENTO` FLOAT(53), 
    `GOODWILL` FLOAT(53)
)
```

Before replaces one column might be like "ATIVOS REALIZADOS APÓS COMPRA DE RODOVIA E LIQUIDAÇÃO DE LUCROS", which would result in the 64 characters error.

My replace library are following this pattern:

```py
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['IMPOSTO DE RENDA'], value='IR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['REDUÇÃO'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['AUMENTO'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['EFEITO'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['PERDA'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['GANHO'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['CONSTITUIÇÃO'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['REVERSÃO'], value='VAR')
balativo = balativo.replace(regex=['CAIXA DESPENDIDO'], value='DESPESA')
...
```

So I was wondering if there is a different and more efficient approach to automatically match the 64 characters limit, the column names doesn't have to perfectly match the source.

Comment: What is this 64 word limit in mysql? Do you mean max number of columns per table? Or is this the max number of characters (not words) of a column name in mysql?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, its 64 CHARACTERS, not words.

Comment: If you want the column names to make some sense, then I do not think you can do better than the current approach. You could try to use artificial names and provide the true column name as comments in the create table and fetch the comments from the information_schema.columns view later. But using artificial column names will make writing queries a lot more difficult,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an alternative that worked for me, truncating the data, for my database the most important information are in the first words, so truncating works for me, heres the partial code:

```
columnslist = []
columns = list(balativo.columns)
for column in columns:
    if len(column) >= 64:
        column = column[0:63]
        columnslist.append(column)
    else:
        columnslist.append(column)
balativo = balativo.set_axis(columnslist, axis=1)
```

This worked for uploading ~4000 sheets to my database with no errors, so I will mark this as the answer if someone goes through the same.